# GDB on AARCH64 don't display CPSR after math operations

Tags: assembly, gdb, arm64

I wrote the following assembly code to test debugging:

```
.section .text
    .global _start
        _start:
            mov  x0, #0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
            mov  x1, #1

            cmp  x1, #1
            cmp  x2, #7

            add  x0, x1, x0
```

... and I noticed a strange behavor. The **cmp** commands update the CPSR as expected but when I add **0x1** to **0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF** then I don't see an Update of the CSPR and I don't see the expected overflow-flag!

Is that a but in GDB or do I understand the function of the ARM chip wrong? Why the flags get not updated after a arithmetic operation? Or do they get updated and GDB just don't display them?

Comment: The `add` instruction does not change any flags.  Only `adds` does.  Refer to the ARMv8 Architecture Reference Manual for details.

Comment: Man, I read that aritmetic instructions update the flags but I most have overlooked that there is beside add and conditional add also a adds to update the CPSR. Thanks!

Comment: Read the ARM carefully.  Most AArch64 instructions do not set CSPR.  Most that do have a mnemonic suffixed with S.

Comment: Anyway, adding 1 to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF would cause a *carry* but not an *overflow* (in terms of signed arithmetic you are adding 1 + (-1) = 0 which does not overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Just to give this an answer:

The `add` instruction on ARM64 does not set the CSPR flags (Negative, Zero, Carry, oVerflow).  Use `adds` instead if you want the flags set.

As a general rule, most arithmetic instructions on ARM64 do not set flags; only their `s`-suffixed variants do so.  This is different from x86 but is generally desirable; with less "pollution" you have more freedom to rearrange instructions, without worrying so much about what comes in between the instruction that sets the flags and the conditional branch or whatever that reads them.